# Adding new fields to existing ORC Files using HIVE

Tags: hive, orc

Appreciate any inputs based on the below scenario -

**AS-IS process -**  From the source system we receive the CSV files. We curate these CSV files using HIVE and load them into s3 into ORC file format. We have accumulated two years of curated historical data in AWS s3 organized in ORC file format partitioned by one of the columns C5.

e.g. Columns in current file (both csv and orc) C1, C2, C3, C4, C5

**TO-BE Process -** The requirement is that the source system is going to add new columns at the end of the csv files. 
Columns in new file C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, **C6, C7**
Fields C6 and C7 will need to be populated going forward.

In Hive we are currently doing and insert overt-write based on the partitioned column C5.

The question here is can we stack the new files (having additional fields C6 and C7) onto the existing ORC files? If yes, what would be the recommended steps. Do we need to rewrite the historical files and create blank fields for C6 and C7 as we will never get the historical data for those fields? or it will automatically show NULL ?

Comment: By default, an ALTER TABLE does not change the column list for the *existing* partitions -- Hive will detect the discrepancy and show the missing cols with Nulls. But future partitions will have the columns in their ORC data files. _(except in old versions of Hive that had bizarre bugs, ca. 2015)_

Comment: But... the partitioning key is **not** a column; it's always shown at the end, after proper coluns. So your table currently shows `C1, C2, C3, C4, Ck` and after you add 2 more columns it will show `..., C4, C5, Ck`. Remember, the partitioning key is not data, it's metadata...

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, I was planning to drop the hive external table and create the new one with the additional columns. For the new files, the new fields are at the end of the file. For the old file the new fields will not be present. Since the partitions are still the same, I believe, the new external table should work fine - i.e. show values for the new files while will display null for the old files. Nothing should break in this case. Is this understanding correct? Any similar experience and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter for the inputs on the columns and keys. If I read you comment correctly,  can I continue to stack the new files on top of the current files as long as the position of C1 through C4 are constant in the new file and the new fields are defined after that. Since the partition key continues to be the same field - Ck, it will continue to appear at the end - seamlessly.

Comment: Run a test -- create a dummy table with 2 partitions and a few ORC files in each, add the columns, create a new partition, INSERT into that new partition, run some tests queries. In 2015 I saw it crash and burn when using a vectorized SELECT; that bug is fixed, but new bugs may appear any time :-/